# Check if at least one condition is true in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have an array of object tableRows.

```
tableRows = [
    {
        purchase_sales:1000,
        yearFirstRemAmount: 1456,
        capitalServicePurchase:123234,
        otherServicePurchase: 12323,
        otherStuffPurchase: 8903,
        capitaStuffPurchase: 1200,
        currentYearServiceSell: 47856,
        currentYearStuffSell: 100000,
        yearLastRemAmount: 20000
    }
    {
        purchase_sales:23430,
        yearFirstRemAmount: 12500,
        capitalServicePurchase: 1000010,
        otherServicePurchase: 12360,
        otherStuffPurchase: 12300,
        capitaStuffPurchase: 12000,
        currentYearServiceSell: 123123,
        currentYearStuffSell: 12111,
        yearLastRemAmount: 13120
    }
]
```

How do I check if at least one of the 9 key pairs value is greater than or equal to 100000 for each index.

Below Code didn't work:

```
const handleValidation = (index)=>{
    if(tableRows[index].purchase_sales<100000 || tableRows[index].yearFirstRemAmount<100000 || tableRows[index].capitalServicePurchase<100000 || tableRows[index].otherServicePurchase<100000 || tableRows[index].otherStuffPurchase<100000 || tableRows[index].capitaStuffPurchase<100000 || tableRows[index].currentYearServiceSell<100000 || tableRows[index].currentYearStuffSell<100000 || tableRows[index].yearLastRemAmount<100000 ){
                alert("'At least one amount should be greater than or equal to 100000!!!")
            }
}
```

Is there a better and more concise way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, you can convert an object to an array or convert its values to an array and then use `some` method` on array.

But if your object may have other keys and you want to check specific properties:

1. You can create an array of keys that you want to check:

```
const keys = [
    'purchase_sales',
    'yearFirstRemAmount',
    'capitalServicePurchase',
    'otherServicePurchase',
    'otherStuffPurchase',
    'capitaStuffPurchase',
    'currentYearServiceSell',
    'currentYearStuffSell',
    'yearLastRemAmount'
];
```

2. Create a function which receives an object as an input and validates

```
function validate (obj) {
    for (key of keys) {
        if(obj[key] >= 100000) {
            // Do something here.
            // For instance: return true;
        }
    }
    // There is no property with a value greater or equal to 100000.
    // Do something here.
    // For instance: return false;
}
```

3. Validate your data. Something like this:

```
    const isValid = tableRows.map(validate).every(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `map` and `some`:

```
const threshold = 1000000;
const yourAnswer = tableRows.map(Object.values).some(value => value >= threshold);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleValidation = (index)=>{
 
 if (Object.values(tableRows[index]).some(value => value < 100000)) {
    alert("'At least one amount should be greater than or equal to 100000!!!")
  }
}
```

Comment: The logic on this is wrong, this will alert if any value is less than 100k, where it should only alert if all values are less than 100k

Comment: I copied op` code which used `<` instead of `>=` because I thought it could be a mistake in the description

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` method to filter the array, and `Object.values` keys value of each object, and `some` to check if there a key equal or more than `100000`

```js
const tableRows = [
    {
        purchase_sales:1000,
        yearFirstRemAmount: 1456,
        capitalServicePurchase:123234,
        otherServicePurchase: 12323,
        otherStuffPurchase: 8903,
        capitaStuffPurchase: 1200,
        currentYearServiceSell: 47856,
        currentYearStuffSell: 100000,
        yearLastRemAmount: 20000
    },
    {
        purchase_sales:23430,
        yearFirstRemAmount: 12500,
        capitalServicePurchase: 1000010,
        otherServicePurchase: 12360,
        otherStuffPurchase: 12300,
        capitaStuffPurchase: 12000,
        currentYearServiceSell: 123123,
        currentYearStuffSell: 12111,
        yearLastRemAmount: 13120
    }
]


const rows = tableRows.filter(row => {
  return Object.values(row).some(value => value >= 100000)
})


console.log(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that all entries of `tableRows[index]` are numbers you want to check, you can do this with `Object.prototype.values` and `Array.prototype.some` (which also short-circuits)

```js
const tableRows=[{purchase_sales:1000,yearFirstRemAmount:1456,capitalServicePurchase:123234,otherServicePurchase:12323,otherStuffPurchase:8903,capitaStuffPurchase:1200,currentYearServiceSell:47856,currentYearStuffSell:100000,yearLastRemAmount:20000},{purchase_sales:23430,yearFirstRemAmount:12500,capitalServicePurchase:1000010,otherServicePurchase:12360,otherStuffPurchase:12300,capitaStuffPurchase:12000,currentYearServiceSell:123123,currentYearStuffSell:12111,yearLastRemAmount:13120},{purchase_sales:0,yearFirstRemAmount:0,capitalServicePurchase:0,otherServicePurchase:0,otherStuffPurchase:0,capitaStuffPurchase:0,currentYearServiceSell:0,currentYearStuffSell:0,yearLastRemAmount:0}];

const handleValidation = (index) => {
  if (!Object.values(tableRows[index]).some((v) => v >= 100000)) {
    alert("'At least one amount should be greater than or equal to 100000!!! for index " + index)
  }
}

tableRows.forEach((_row, idx) => handleValidation(idx));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const tableRows = [
{
    purchase_sales:1000,
    yearFirstRemAmount: 1456,
    capitalServicePurchase:123234,
    otherServicePurchase: 12323,
    otherStuffPurchase: 8903,
    capitaStuffPurchase: 1200,
    currentYearServiceSell: 47856,
    currentYearStuffSell: 100000,
    yearLastRemAmount: 20000
},
{
    purchase_sales:23430,
    yearFirstRemAmount: 12500,
    capitalServicePurchase: 1000010,
    otherServicePurchase: 12360,
    otherStuffPurchase: 12300,
    capitaStuffPurchase: 12000,
    currentYearServiceSell: 123123,
    currentYearStuffSell: 12111,
    yearLastRemAmount: 13120
}
];

const handleValidation = (index) => {
  const found = Object.values(tableRows[index]).some((x) => x > 100000);
  if(!found)
  {
    alert("'At least one amount should be greater than or equal to 100000!!!");
  }
  console.log(index,found)
}

tableRows.forEach((item, index) => handleValidation(index));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const tableRows = [
    {
        purchase_sales:1000,
        yearFirstRemAmount: 1456,
        capitalServicePurchase:123234,
        otherServicePurchase: 12323,
        otherStuffPurchase: 8903,
        capitaStuffPurchase: 1200,
        currentYearServiceSell: 47856,
        currentYearStuffSell: 100000,
        yearLastRemAmount: 20000
    },
    {
        purchase_sales:23430,
        yearFirstRemAmount: 12500,
        capitalServicePurchase: 1000010,
        otherServicePurchase: 12360,
        otherStuffPurchase: 12300,
        capitaStuffPurchase: 12000,
        currentYearServiceSell: 123123,
        currentYearStuffSell: 12111,
        yearLastRemAmount: 13120
    }
];
let data = tableRows.filter((row)=>{
   return Object.values(row).map(value => value >= 100000)
});
console.log(data);
```